# How to print the array value inside the JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I use the API to call the PHP page. This API have this JSON post data

```
{"product[]":["Layer Management System","Broiler Management System"]}
```

how can I get the data separately for product[0]. I use this method

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo  $data["product[]"];
```

but it was not woking and show the error below

```
<b>Notice</b>: Array to string conversion in
<b>/production/test_reg3.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
Array
```

And one more method is

```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    print_r($data);
    echo  $data["product[0]"];
```

it shows the error below

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: product[0] in
<b>/production/test_reg3.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

I need to store product[] value in any variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$data["product[]"][0]
```

Don't get confused between the brackets which are part of the PHP syntax and the brackets which are part of the property name.